# Negative Testing for PayPal using Sandbox with VB.NET - how to simulate different scenarios?

Tags: vb.net, testing, paypal, sandbox

I have a website written in VB.NET that implements PayPal for payments. This is all working fine for successful payments, but I need to be able to simulate scenarios of a failed transaction, pending transaction, etc.

I have read the [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf), which starts on page 47. I enabled Negative Testing in a business account that I created in a Sandbox, but I am not getting desired results.

To simulate an error, as specified in the documentation, I'm passing an error code to Token, which is then used in a request to DoExpressCheckoutPayment - code below - but instead of this raising the error 10417, the response says Invalid Token:

```
Dim oldToken As String
With RequestDetails
    oldToken = .Token
    .Token = "10417"
End With

Dim request As New DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestType
request.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails = RequestDetails

Dim response As DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType
response = DirectCast(caller.Call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment", request), 
    DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType)
```

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in the code above so that I can't trigger a correct error?
2. How do I simulate a response where the status is Pending, Processed, Failed, etc.?

Comment: Can you link the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing this about a week ago and was receiving the same problem, now, I no longer receive an error:

### API Request:

```
METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment 
VERSION=82 
token=10755 
PayerID=GNT5WLV6WKLYW 
PAYMENTACTION=Sale 
AMT=456 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=458 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=458.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=20.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=46.20 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=test EC payment 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Books 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=154.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=ABC123 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=CDs 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=50.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=BY-Z4736 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=3
```

### API Response:

```
TIMESTAMP=2011-09-27T20:39:57Z
CORRELATIONID=13126abeb4615
ACK=Failure
VERSION=82
BUILD=2133933
L_ERRORCODE0=10755
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unsupported Currency.
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Currency is not supported
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

I did find an [article](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/general-support/doexpresscheckoutpayment-negative-testing-not-working) on x.com that deals with this issue as well.

Comment: The link to the article is dead